# Root test shows convergence but having trouble showing ratio test is inconclusive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am given the series:

$\frac{1}{3}$ + $\frac{1}{5}$ + $\frac{1}{3^2}$ + $\frac{1}{5^2}$ + $\frac{1}{3^3}$ + $\frac{1}{5^3}$ + .... and so on...

I am trying to show that the root test shows convergence, which i did by just splitting the series into two series of $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ and show that because both series converges, the addition of the two converges.

However, the problem I have is trying to show that the ratio test gives no information. When I solve it, I still get that it converges. Help?

Comment: $\frac{1}{3^n}/\frac{1}{5^n}=(\frac{5}{3})^n$ and this tends to $\infty$. But $\frac{1}{5^n}/\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{3}{5})^n$ tends to $0$. So the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at the $\lim \sup a_{n+1} / a_n$ and $\lim \inf.$  If the ratio test was going to give you useful information, they should agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a_{2n-1} = \frac{1}{3^n}$ and $a_{2n} = \frac{1}{5^n}$

So, for $n$ big enough,
$$\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}} = \frac{\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{5^n}} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{5}{3} \right)^n > 1$$
and
$$\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n-1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{5^{n}}}{\frac{1}{3^n}} = \left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^n < 1$$

So you can't conclude anything

Comment: They may both tend to 1 however.(Which of course, in this case we know is not true.)

Comment: @daruma : and if it converge to 1, you cannot conclude with the ratio test

Answer (score 0):

Taking the ratio between $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{3^n}/\frac{1}{5^n}=(\frac{5}{3})^n$ and this tends to $\infty$.

But when we take the ratio between $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n+2}$ we get $\frac{1}{5^n}/\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{3}{5})^n$ tends to $0$.

So the limit doesn't exist.
Hence the test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $$u_n=\frac 1 {3^n}+\frac 1 {5^n}$$ you have $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{3^{-n-1}+5^{-n-1}}{3^{-n}+5^{-n}}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2\times 3^{n-1}}{5 \left(3^n+5^n\right)}<\frac{1}{3}$$ On another hand $$\frac 2 {5^n}< u_n <\frac 2 {3^n}$$ which leads to $$\frac 12 <\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_n <1$$